# what is correct architecture of my pc AMD or INTEL?

Tags: cpu, 64-bit, computer-building, intel-core-i7

i was trying to get the info about my system processor architecture and saw two different answers

1. from windows explorer
2. from cmd prompt using "SET Processor" command

and i got intel i7 and amd64 respectively
[as youcan see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4k2m.png)

can someone give me clear picture about amd and intel cpu's
[i have gone through this question](https://superuser.com/questions/271437/amd-cpu-clones-of-intel-chips) but need more information about those 2 commands which i ran, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct, but they refer to different kinds of architectures.

- "Intel" is the manufacturer of this particular CPU, and "i7-3612QM" is the model. It describes *how* the hardware was built.
- "amd64" (aka "x86_64") is the name for the *instruction set* that the CPU understands. It describes *what* the CPU was built to do.

Nearly all 64-bit CPUs that you'll find in a PC – whether they're Intel CPUs or AMD CPUs or VIA CPUs – will be made for the "amd64" aka "x86_64" instruction set, because that's what PCs traditionally use.

Comment: i thought amd is company which uses arm as instruction set can you give an idea of difference between AMR and AMD?

Comment: AMD primarily manufactures CPUs using the x86 instruction set. Note that the original 32-bit x86 was invented by Intel, but extended to 64-bit by AMD, that's why you see Intel x86_64 being called "amd64" even if it's an Intel CPU and Intel architecture.

Comment: ARM is a _completely_ different instruction set – popular on phones/tablets. The company overseeing it is called ARM as well, or "Arm" these days. (Yes, ARM also has 32-bit and 64-bit versions, and "arm64" exists too. Don't confuse it with amd64.)

Comment: Intel's 64bit ISA is IA64, Itanium architecture which was a completely new CPU design with limited backward compatibility. (Optimization was good in theory, but bad in practice.) 
Shortly after IA64 released, AMD created AMD64 to extend the existing Intel x86 ISA to 64bits with great backward compatibility. This was a commercial success. "x86_64" as a synonym for amd64 is a subtle marketing by Intel to obscure its AMD origin. AMD first obtained x86 when it produced 16-bit 80286 for Intel under a second source tech-exchange contract pushed by IBM (who was avoiding vender lock-in).

Answer (score 0):

The amd64 architecture is the instruction language windows is using, 64 bit, not an amd processor.  The correct answer is from windows explorer the I7.  AMD is just part of the instruction / architecture name.